# C# WPF Chess binding and ObservableCollection, how to modify?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, chess

so i'm doing a chess game just to learn c# and WPF.

Have been googling around alot and have so far came up with some code, my problem now is that when i create chess pieces on my board i dont know how to modify them inside the observbleCollection, for example removing one piece. With this code i can add the pieces to the board.

But how can i modify it after i have created it?

```
this.ChessBoardd.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ChessPiece>
{
    new ChessPiece{Type_ = Piece.Pawn, Player_ = PiecePlayer.Black, Posx_ = 30, Posy_ = 50},
    new ChessPiece{Type_ = Piece.Pawn, Player_ = PiecePlayer.Black, Posx_ = 30, Posy_ = 50} 
};
```

In the same file i have the following code:

```
public class ChessPiece : INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private int posx_;
    private int posy_;       

    public int Posx_
    {
        get { return this.posx_; }
        set { this.posx_ = value; OnPropertyChanged("Posx_"); }            
    }

    public int Posy_
    {
        get { return this.posy_; }
        set { this.posy_ = value; OnPropertyChanged("Posy_"); } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here from my idea was that i could some how change my observablecollection array for example (this doesn't work since i dont know how to do it) and then the ui would update the board automatlicy since i have the infotifyproperychangin and binding in the xaml file,

```
this.ChessBoardd.IteamsSource[0].Posx_ = 50;
```

Any ideas on this? Should i approch from a diffrent way?

Comment: Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` not `INotifyPropertyChanging`.

Comment: Ah, i ofcourse it should be that, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Item` method of the ObservableCollection class.

So the right way to implement this

```
this.ChessBoardd.IteamsSource[0].Posx_ = 50;
```

is:

```
this.ChessBoardd.IteamsSource.Item(0).Posx_ = 50;
```

Also on your properties it's a nice optimization if you check

```
set
{
     if(value!=posy)
     {
         posy = value
         PropertyChanged("PosY");
     }
 }
```

Oh and use INotifyPropertyChanged instead of INotifyPropertyChanging

Comment: Even better; `ItemsSource` should be bound; and then you don't ever access the collection directly, you deal with the bound objects off of the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Thanks for the answear! Did not get this.ChessBoardd.IteamsSource.Item to work however, my visual could not find item for some reason. Could not find it on msdn page either for itemsource. Did find a soultion that did work for me tho, i added "public ObservableCollection<ChessPiece> x { get; set; }" and then just x.add(new chesspiece(){ values}); then i can change however i want :)